# Developer Story not Showing All of my GitHub Repos

Tags: discussion, support, developer-story

In Developer Story, when I click `Open Source` -> `Import from GitHub` a list of my project appears - except it's very incomplete. I've got over a hundred open source repos, and the alphabetized shows through `F` or so.

Is there a way to supply a direct link and let Developer Story import the rest automatically?